# How to save star rating value into a local storage and how it display when the page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, rating-system

I have developed a web page for the star ratings. I need to save the star value into local storage when the user clicks on stars and need to display that value on stars when the page reloads.

**This is what I tried**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is Home page</h1>
    <p>This is a testing page for rating.</p>
    <div>
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="1" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="2" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="3" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="4" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="5" src="./img/star.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="6" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="7" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="8" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="9" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="10" src="./img/star.png" />
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
<script>
    function rate() {
        const { id } = event.target;
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
            } else {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/star.png");
            }
        }
    }

    function rate1() {
        const { id } = event.target;
        var i;
        for (i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
            } else {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/star.png");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. How can I use 'localStorage.setItem()' to set star values and how to display that star value when the page reloads?

Comment: when you get the rating save it by calling `localStorage.setItem('starRating',rating);` where `rating`is your rating and when you want to retreive it call `let rating = localStorage.setItem('starRating');` which will fetch the value into a variable called `rating`

Comment: Using the `id` attribute is a poor choice to store the star value of a image. What if you have multiple ratings on one page?

Comment: yes, I have multiple ratings on my page. any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well for localstorage you can use something like

```
localStorage.setItem('star', 'theStarClickedID');
```

and then you get it back with

```
var star = localStorage.getItem('star');
```

then you check the value of star and depending on that you put all lower to filledstar

EDIT: another thing, for this part

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
            document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
        } else {
            document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/star.png");
        }
    }
```

i think you can do

```
for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(id); i++) {
     document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
}
```

SECOND EDIT: what you asked for

```
<script>
    load()
    function load() {
        var star = localStorage.getItem('star');;
        for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(star); i++) {
            
            document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about this and I need to display the "localStorage.getItem('star')' value on stars

Comment: well you just do a load function for exemple, and for id of the stars you change the image no?

Comment: Could you please provide some code samples?

Comment: i edited :), havent tried it, sorry if its not working PS: you should put it in javascript file, and add the page loaded verification

Comment: Ok I'll try this. could you please tell me where to set "localStorage.setItem('star', 'theStarClickedID');" this code line?

Comment: well you put onclick directly on HTML, you should care and separate your codes :/ but it should work if you put it in the function you use to switch stars (i see you have two function so you need to care of names)

Comment: oh and i did not precised but you have to verify that localstorage is not empty or i guess it will give you an error :)

Comment: OK, Thank you very much for your help. I'll try all the steps.

Comment: Sure! if there is any problem, you can post it here i think, also if it is not the case and you need help doing different files for your html, js, css, start a private discussion (you need to write a comment and click "automaticlly move this discussion to chat")

Comment: I did it with your steps and it working fine. Thanks for your help. And also I have another question similar to this and it's about the radio button. could you please help me solve it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234441/discussion-between-sidath-and-dafuqi).

Comment: I have another problem with this star rating. If the user clicks twice on the same star, how to unload all the star rating values? that means if the user clicks on 3 stars for the rating and again click on the 3rd star how to disappear all the rating stars value?